# Bash: No such file/directory error

Tags: bash, archive

I created below script that will find files in two directories with more than 5 days old and compressed files will be moved to another directory.
However, i had a problem if there are no files which is  +5 days old in those 2 directories, I got the errors

```
find: `/home/folder1/*.*': No such file or directory
find: `/home/folder2/*.*': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/home/folder1/*.Z': No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat `/home/folder2/*.Z': No such file or directory
```

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /home/folder1/*.* /home/folder2/*.* -type -f -mtime +5 -exec compress {} \;
mv /home/folder1/*.Z /home/folder1/archive

mv /home/folder2/*.Z /home/folder2/archive
```

Comment: the glob in your find params extends to actual list of file names, that's how your errors come out.

Answer (score 2):

`find` doesn't need those globs to do what you want it too (unless you are trying to specifically ignore files that do not have a `.` in their names). You can just drop them.

```
find /home/folder1 /home/folder2 -type -f -mtime +5 -exec compress {} \;
```

Then instead of blindly using `mv` on a blob for a file which may or may not exist test for them first (or silence the errors).

```
# nullglob makes the globs result in empty strings instead of staying the glob when they don't match any files.
shopt -s nullglob

f1files=(/home/folder1/*.Z)
if [ "${#f1files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    mv "${f1files[@]}" /home/folder1/archive
fi

f2files=(/home/folder2/*.Z)
if [ "${#f1files[@]}" -gt 0 ]; then
    mv "${f1files[@]}" /home/folder2/archive
fi
```

That all being said your `find` command is **going** to find the `.Z` archive files you are creating under `/home/folder#/archive` and it **will** re-compress them in the `archive` folder. (Unless `compress` is smart enough not to do anything to a `.Z` file but it will still get run on those files.)

You almost certainly do **not** want that so you need to handle that either by using an archive directory **not** under the folder you are calling `find` on or by excluding them from the find command specifically.